# Return model where the pivot entry exists

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, bookshelf.js

I'm using BookshelfJS. I have two models `users` and `posts`. Obviously, the relationship here is many to many. So I have a pivot table `post_user`.

Now, given a `user_id`, I want to find all the `posts` for that user. So far, I've managed to do this using `knex`:

```
knex.select()
    .from('post_user')
    .where('user_id', user_id)
    .then(function (pivots) {
        // Now loop through pivots and return all the posts
        // Using pivot.post_id
        pivots.map(function(pivot) {})
    });
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to define the many-to-many relationship in your Bookshelf models. Something like this:

```
var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  posts: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Post);
  }
});

var Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'posts',
  users: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(User);
  }
});
```

By convention, the pivot table Bookshelf would be using is `posts_users` (table names combined with `_`, starting from the table that is alphabetically first). It should contain a `user_id` and a `post_id` (and a coposite PK of those two). If you don't wish to rename the pivot table, see the [documentation for `belongsToMany`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-belongsToMany) for instructions on how to define the table and ids of your pivot table.

After this, you can query your model with Bookshelf:

```
return new User().where('id', user_id)
    .fetch({withRelated: 'posts'})
    .then(function (user) {
       var postCollection = user.get('posts');
       // do something with the posts
    });
```

See also the documentation for [fetch](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-fetch).